# Getting a simple ServiceLoader to work in Java using 2 supplementary Modules

Tags: java, spi, serviceloader

I am fairly new to using ServiceLoader and I am trying to get a very simple example up and running.

Currently have 4 Modules: BLCore, BLInterface, BLMod1, BLMod2

```
BLCore depends on: BLInterface, BLMod1, BLMod2
BLInterface depends on: Nonne
BLMod1 depends on: BLInterface
BLMod2 depends on: BLInterface
```

BLCore contains the main method and contains the following:

```
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(BeanInterface val : ServiceLoader.load(BeanInterface.class)){
            System.out.println("You are a "+val.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

And BLInterface has a single String method that just prints out a name or so.

The structure is as follows:

[image]

The code can compile but the ServiceLoader does not detect Module1 and Module2, any ideas?

----STATUS----
All errors removed, still not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use package rather than the default package. For example `com.example`.

In Java 8 (excluding problems due to module):

- In `BLMod1` project, `META-INF/services/com.example.BeanInterface` must contains `com.example.Module1`
- In `BLMod2` project, `META-INF/services/com.example.BeanInterface` must contains `com.example.Module2`
- In `BLCore` configuration (Maven, Gradle or even your IDE), you must ensure to reference the `BLMod1` and `BLMod2`: it must be available in the class path when you execute your main.
- Be sure that `Module1` and `Module2` have a public constructor.

If you are using Java 9++, you may also have to add appropriate line to your `module-info.java`:

```
module com.example.module1 {      
  provides com.example.BeanInterface
      with com.example.Module1;
}
```

That's where the package will be useful: you probably can't use modules without a proper package.

You may also want to read the Javadoc for that: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: Thank you, I will read it trough tomorrow (The link). I tried to get it working following your example but could not get it to work. But I need to understand the module-info.java files a bit more I believe as those gives me errors at the moment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that where you problem is, the module-info.

Comment: Okay I have cleaned it up a bit and removed all errors from maven and module.info files. It gives no errors but it does not seems to work, and I am sure I am missing a tiny detail. I have added a new image above if you still are able. :-)

Comment: See my answer: your module-info (in BLMod1/BLMod2) **must** tell what it provides.

Comment: You were right! Could not get it working at first but it cleared up nicely now. Thanks a bunch for the help!